# Dell 15R overheating

Tags: 12.04, ati, dell, overheating

Hello after installing Ubuntu 12.04 my laptop is constantly running above 60°C. I have installed the relative third party drivers but still the same. My laptop is a Dell 15R n5010, i5.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Manhattan 
[Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]).
```

Comment: Run `top` in a terminal window to see if any proccess uses too many CPU cycles. Try Ubuntu2d (aka Unity2d) as session from the login screen.

Comment: Im happy with 60° on my Dell laptop.. Im often at 80 playing videos ..

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug opened for this problem on Launchpad.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-driver-ati/+bug/1021024

I have had this problem since Ubuntu 11.10 and it has not been solved yet..I also tried using Jupiter, but the problem is only delayed for some minutes.

Probably, the only way to solve this problem is to switch off the Ati card and use the Intel integrated card (by bios or manually)..

[How to completely shutdown Ati card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96983/how-to-completely-shutdown-ati-card)