# Does every i5 i7 intel processor have intel graphics on board?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I am asking because I can make a bargain on such a laptop, but it is advertised with AMD graphics and AFAIK driver support for AMD is not that great.

If so, how would Linux react seeing two graphics adaptors?

Comment: Where does the second graphics adaptor come in? It's a laptop right? It will have one graphics adaptor ( in most cases ).

Comment: Many notebooks have hybrid graphics these days - an Intel GPU for light tasks, and an ATI or Nvidia one for gaming. Unfortunately, neither Linux, nor the vendors provide support for that technology at the moment.

Comment: This question does not seem to be about Ubuntu at all; instead, this appears to be a pure hardware question. Therefore, this may be closed as off-topic. You might want to post this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @mikewhatever I know that propriertary NVidia is very stable and usable, once you are in user mode. I am no gamer; As long as it has Intel HD graphics I am fine. Even WebGL is starting to be ok.

Comment: @EliahKagan It is, as it will influence my buying decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware all core i3/i5/i7 processors come with the Intel GPU built into the processor and are sometimes used for dual graphics laptops with nvidia or ati...  Their IS a way to disable ATI graphics though and just use Intel's own...

[How to completely shutdown Ati card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96983/how-to-completely-shutdown-ati-card)